# retrieve full geometry grid information from matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.zeros((3, 3))

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(131)
ax2 = plt.subplot(132)
ax3 = plt.subplot(133)
axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3]

for ax in axes:
    im = ax.imshow(data)
```

The resulting figure `fig` has 3 `AxesSubplot` children, one for each subplot. Their geometry

```
for child in fig.get_children():
    try:
        print(child.get_geometry())
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

```
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 3)
```

makes sense.

Now let's add some color bars:

```
for ax in axes:
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
```

*Now* the geometries are reported as

```
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 2)
```

Hm, how to make sense of those?

Comment: I molded this into [a matplotlib bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7225).